# Magento CE 1.8 Password Storage

Tags: security, ce-1.8.0.0

CE 1.8 inherits from EE 1.13 and lists as a change: 
*“The cryptographic methods used to store passwords were improved to enhance security”*

As far as I know, earlier versions used APR1 which is a 1000 iteration loop of MD5 with a 32-bit salt, then encodes the 128-bit result in 6-bit chunks to a text readable format using a fixed 64 entry array of printable characters.

How has this changed in the new versions? There does not seem to be any documentation with any details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Community Edition

In the old version (CE 1.7.0.2) magento hashed passwords with md5 and a 2 char salt. No iterations, just one hashing.

With 1.8 the method changed ... a little bit. They changed the salt lentgh from 2 to 32. The method is still bad.

#### Enterprise Edition

The enterprise edition does nearly the same. The difference is (before 1.13!) they use `sha256()`. I don't know what they use in 1.13

#### Advertisement for PBKDF2

If you want to hash the user passwords in a better way, you can install my module:
https://github.com/ikonoshirt/pbkdf2

It uses [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) for hashing password.

Comment: I totally did not believe you, and then spent a few hours digging through the code.... unfortunately you are correct. I understand why they did not want to give any details :/ Does EE use the same method?

Comment: I should also note that the method they use to generate the salt returns a char of a-z,A-Z,0-9 which only has 62 unique values, so a 2 byte salt only had 1612 unique vals, the new method is equivalent to 190-bits of salt entropy (very good compared to v1.7 which was 10-bits).

Comment: added EE and a little ad